# spring jpa - get all entities with discriminatorType

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have two entities that inherit from `ExerciceFramework` entity, how can i get all `ExerciseFramework` with their discriminatorType   `professionType`, the `findAll()` function doesn't return this attribute

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "professionType", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class ExerciseFrameworkEntity implements Serializable { }

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("ETP")
public class Company extends ExerciseFrameworkEntity { }

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("ETA")
public class Establishment extends ExerciseFrameworkEntity { }

@Repository
public interface ExerciceFrameworkRepository extends JpaRepository<ExerciseFramework, String> {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just declare a new Repository interface for exactly the subtype you want.
like:

```
CompanyRepo extends JpaRepository<Company, String>
```

When I had the same case as you, I just created 3 repositories interfaces, one for the base class which returns all types, and then 2 extensions of that interface that specifically return the subtypes. It's easily controlled by Generics.
In your case, something like:

```
 ExerciceFrameworkRepo<T extends ExceriseFrameworkEntity> extends JpaRepository<T, String>
 CompanyRepo extends ExerciseRepo<Company>
 EstablishmentRepo extends ExerciseRepo<Establishment>
```

Comment: When i execute exerciceFrameworkRepo.findAll(), i get all the ExerciseFramework but how can i differentiate between them if one is of type company or establishment

Comment: How does your FrameworkEntity look like inside? Have you tried to just declare the field for the discrimator column and access it like any other regular porperty? I think this is like the easiest way to do this. An alternative would be a less elegant instanceof check.